# How to do a 1-D fft using pycuda?

Tags: python, gpu, fft, pycuda

Hi I am attempting to a simple 1D-FFT transform on a signal. This is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hilbert, chirp

duration = 1.0
fs = 400.0
samples = int(fs*duration)
t = np.arange(samples) / fs
signal = chirp(t, 20.0, t[-1], 100.0)
```

---

```
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda import gpuarray
import numpy as np
from skcuda import fft
```

---

```
def fft_gpu1(signal):
  x_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(signal)
  x_hat = gpuarray.empty_like(x_gpu, dtype=np.complex64)
  plan = fft.Plan(x_gpu.shape,np.float32,np.complex64)
  fft.fft(x_gpu, x_hat, plan)
  return x_hat.get()
```

---

```
print(fft_gpu1(signal))
```

---

However, the result I get is:

```
[nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj
 nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj
 nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj
 nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj nan+nanj
...
  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j
  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j
  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j  0. +0.j]
```

---

Any insight on why im getting this issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The signal should be of type float32, not float64:

```
x_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(signal.astype(np.float32))
```